# Initialize table with array of objects

Tags: java, swing, multidimensional-array, jtable

I am having a problem initializing a JTable from a FOR with BD or an array.

My problem is the example tableFilterDemo.java, I need the funcionality of this, 
but when I want load data of my BD or an arraylist I have the problem.

I need load the array of objects with a FOR getting all the lines of file or rows of table

```
private Object[][] data = {
    { "Mary", "Campione", "Snowboarding"},
    { "John", "guifru", "skyiin"},};
```

Comment: What does "FOR" or "BD" mean?

Comment: This question is very unclear.  What problem are you having? Post the error.

Comment: BD (database), for(int i = 0; i; i++)

Comment: Quit cross posting: http://www.coderanch.com/t/548958/GUI/java/Initialize-table-array-objects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always use the DefaultTableModel which uses a Vector of Vectors to hold the data in the TableModel. So for each row in the table you create a Vector and add each column to the Vecter. Then you add the row Vector to a second Vector. This way you don't need to hardcode the size of the Arrays in advance. [Table From Database](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/03/12/table-from-database/) shows how you can use this approach.

Or you can always use a custom TableModel if you want to display custom Ojects that are stored in an ArrayList. The [Row Table Model](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/21/row-table-model/) provides some general support for storing objects in an ArrayList. You would also want to look at the `BeanTableModel` for a full implementation and a further example of how to do a custom implementation.

Answer (score 2):

You have two ways:

- you set the objects directly to the `JTable` by invoking the right constructor (which is `JTable(Object[][] rowData, Object[] columnNames)`) and this is quite easy and good but just manages static tables
- you use a model, like in the example you are talking about: you use a class that extends `AbstractTableModel` in which you override the right methods to map the bidimensional collection to the right behaviors.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that I have understood your problem.
Anyway, if your table have 3 columns and you have defined the table model as defined [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data), you have to itrate your array and put the values in the table in this way:

```
for(int i=0; i < data.length; i++){
  for(int j=0; j < data[i].length; j++){
    table.setValueAt(data[i][j], i, j);
  }
}
```

This is the declaration of the method:
    setValueAt(Object aValue, int row, int column)

If you want to convert an arrayList to an array you can:

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList;
String[] data = new String[arrayList.size()];
data = arrayList.toArray(data);
```

Bye Luca

Comment: its ok but there are a problem data have not data, is empty. I need add to data the info from a database or arraylist

Comment: @Esteban c Can you give me the declaration of your arraylist?

Comment: fila[0] = rs.getString(1);
fila[1] = rs.getString(2);
fila[2] = rs.getString(3);
fila[3] = rs.getString(4);

Comment: @Esteban c Are you Italian? Anyway is fila and array? `String[] fila`

Comment: @Estenan c I modified the answer but I'm not sure I understood your problem

Comment: private Object[][] data = {
    { "Mary", "Campione", "Snowboarding"},
    { "John", "guifru", "skyiin"},}; 
 
my problem is the info is in a database and cant implement this.
I want complete the array of objects with a cycle with my array or resultset
but the Object[][] data is immovable

Comment: @Esteban, do you actually read the answers given to you? You have been given examples of how to load data from a database into a table over an hour ago.

Comment: yes but im not sure that it will work. I want to remove all doubts